# TFS Release - Fetch Build Artifact fails

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**I have a TFS UI build definition** for a c# unit test project.
Before the build finishes, the artifacts are published using the “Publish Build Artifacts” task (published to Azure Pipelines).
It’s built on an agent that runs on Windows10 x64 (but built using the “Visual Studio Build” task using both x86 and x64 platforms).

**I also have a TFS UI release environment**, which runs on a deployment group, which in turn needs to fetch the build artifacts of said build using the “Fetch Build Artifact” task.

When the release runs on an agent that runs on a x64 Windows10 or x64-Windows7 machine, all goes well.

But, when the release runs on an agent that runs on a x86 Windows 7 machine, the task “Fetch Build Artifact” fails with the error:
**The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform**

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I’ve tried everything I can think of, but I’m relatively new to TFS.

**Notes:**

**My agent version for the build machine is 2.141.1.

**My agent version for the deployment group machine is 2.160.1

**I’ve tried building on an x86 win7 machine - “fetch build artifact” in the release still doesn’t work.

**I’ve tried the “download build artifact” instead, still doesn’t work.

**the ”download pipeline artifact” task itself doesn’t work (shows as “preview”).

Comment: Which agent version? Which exact task is that (I don't know a Fetch Build Artifact task)? YAML pipeline or UI created pipeline? Is the build linked as an artifact or are you using an explicit "Download Pipeline Artifact" task in a release stage? I suspect the task that is being used is trying to run an x64 bit executable to download the build artifacts using the Universal Pakagestools.

Comment: And since Win7 is officially no longer supported, you may be out of luck.

Comment: The Windows 7 machine may also be running a too old version of the .NET framework...

Comment: It seems more relevant with the task, but on my side it was all succeed even I built and release it in the agent of x86 win7 machine. To narrow down some possible cause, what about using **Download Pipeline Artifact** or **Download build artifacts** task to download the artifact? what's your TFS version? also, what's the agent version of yours? https://imgur.com/a/tdtkMEq

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

@jessehouwing I'll be at work tomorrow, so I'll be answer to answer the "which agent version?" question then.
Regarding the task - this is it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.fetch-build-artifact
The build isn't linked as an artifact (another build is linked as an artifact), for this build I'm using the explicit "Fetch Build Artifact" while specifying the project and the build.
It sound very probable that the task bis trying to run an x64 executable to download the build artifact... but how can I know for sure?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Thank you to you, too! I'll try building and releasing on x86 win7 machine, and I'll also try the tasks you specified.
Regarding the TFS version and the agent version, I'll be able to answer them tomorrow when I'm at work. Thanks again.

Comment: @jessehouwing also, the x86 machine has both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 installed. I was sure that the .NET Framework version comes with the installation, but it's my mistake that I didn't check. 
Tomorrow I'll update the post with the details. 

What bothers me is that the same release runs on another windows7 machine, and the only difference is that said machine is x64. But in the fetch build artifact task documentation there's nothing I can see about a difference between 64-bit and 32-bit machines.

Comment: @Inbar, I saw you update some info about your agent and pipeline. Also, I saw the agent version you were using is **2.141.1**. Could you try with update this agent to latest version? I am not sure whether this issue is relevant with this, but I ever meet one issue which that customer faced the build failed because of agent too old. And solved by updating the agent to latest version. I wish this would also work for you.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Sorry for the delay - thank you very much for the suggestion! I'll try this when I can, but in my workplace the network is closed, so updating the agent version isn't very simple. I'll update when I know more. Thanks again!